# Opencart "You do not have permission to access this page, please refer to your system administrator"

Tags: opencart, opencart2.x, opencart-module, opencart2.3

Every time I installed a new extension, I got this error:

**error: You do not have permission to access this page, please refer to your system administrator.**

I've already gone to System > User Group, and Add permission to new extension modules (both Access Permission and Modify Permission) but no luck.

I tried to install "2checkout" "Ajax Quick CheckOut" " and get the same error.

Comment: which Opencart version are you using?

Comment: @sayli bhagwat 2.3.0.2

Answer (score 7):

Most likely you're trying to install an extension that is not compatible with OpenCart 2.3.0.2. OpenCart 2.3.X introduced some changes related to extension structure, so you will have to make those changes first

---

**Path change:**

All of the extension types have now moved under a new directory named `extension`.

For example if you have a payment extension then its old structure looked like:

```
admin/controller/payment/xxx.php
admin/model/payment/xxx.php
admin/language/en-gb/payment/xxx.php
admin/view/template/payment/xxx.php
```

Now you must change it to:

```
admin/controller/extension/payment/xxx.php
admin/model/extension/payment/xxx.php
admin/language/en-gb/extension/payment/xxx.php
admin/view/template/extension/payment/xxx.php
```

**Module load path and URL changes:**

And while loading the module you must include `extension` in the path. i.e `$this->load->model('module/:')` now becomes`$this->load->model('extension/module/mymod')`.

This is true for admin URL links as well. `$this->url->link('payment/mymod', 'token=' . $this->session->data['token'], 'SSL')` now becomes `$this->url->link('extension/payment/mymod', 'token=' . $this->session->data['token'], 'SSL')`.

**Class name changes**:

Next change is related to class names. A class named `ControllerModuleMyMod` should be renamed to `ControllerExtensionModuleMyMod`.

These changes are applicable to both `admin` and `catalog`.

---

**Related threads:**

- http://forum.opencart.com/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=164930
- http://forum.opencart.com/viewtopic.php?f=183&t=165958

Comment: Hi Ashwini,
I am new to opencart. I changed all the folder structure, but don't know where to change the module load path and url changes. Please guide me.

Answer (score 0):

It may be required to change in validate() routine of admin controller in module:

```
if (!$this->user->hasPermission('modify', 'module/oldmodule')) {

}
```

to:

```
if (!$this->user->hasPermission('modify', 'extension/module/oldmodule')) {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to admin - system - users - user groups
Edit your administrator and select all then save it.
Problem will be solved.